# EditText and Spinner enable on a button click

Tags: android

I have an ineditable `EditText` and `Spinner`, which show their default values after the page is loaded. Then I want to enable `EditText` and `Spinner` to be editable after the user clicked on a button. 
Any help appreciated Thanx in Advance :)

Comment: Paste your code here..

Comment: you can also use setClickable(true) method after click on button.

Comment: read the official documentations of Android. Find the EditText and Spinner and you will see all methods and properties for these Views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use method:

```
editText.setEnabled(false);
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

in the `onCreate()`-method
and on button click.

```
editText.setEnabled(true);
spinner.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: _@Biraj Zalavadia i tried this method, setEnable false is working setEnabled not working on click.