# How can I disable Spinner in Android and enable it on button click?

Tags: android

I want disable my whole form including edittext and spinner and want to enable it when the user clicks on the edit form button.

Code:

```
 <Spinner
                        android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/etgen"
                        android:entries="@array/gender"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: please do some google before posting questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350566/edittext-and-spinner-enable-on-a-button-click

Comment: I have already googled and tried the possible solutions mentioned over there.@pa

Comment: so post the code what you tried and what problem you facing.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code snippet(s)?

Comment: @Pavan I have edited my question you can see the code..

Comment: @mridula I have attached my code..

Comment: this is by default disable, show the java code where u trying to enable it

Comment: set it in your java code 
spinner.setEnabled(false); to disable 

spinner.setEnabled(true);  to enable

Comment: It is working right after disabling the spinner in java code. @Pavan

Comment: Yep I noticed that working only in java not in XML

Answer (score 12):

What I noticed here about **Spinner** that in **XML** we are not able to **disable** it using

```
 android:enabled='false'
```

It's not possible to enable/disable a Spinner in XML (yet). To do so you have to do it in code.

```
spinner.setEnabled(false);
```

If anyone knows any specific reason why so, they are welcome to edit.

Answer (score 7):

You have to disable it programmatically.

```
spinner.isEnabled = false
```

You can also change the color of it to give the disabled look like mentioned below. It will display the spinner in gray color.

```
 spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
            (parent?.getChildAt(0) as? TextView)?.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)

        }
    }
```

The above code is written in Kotlin. If you find any difficulty I can convert it to Java as well.

Answer (score 3):

Add attribute `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false`" to your Spinner.

**Try this:**

```
<Spinner
    android:background="@drawable/bg_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/etgen"
    android:entries="@array/gender"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: android:enabled="false" is not present

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml attribute `android:enabled="false"` this will disable the particular attribute and if you want to disable the form then you can go with defining it in root element.

Define onClick listener on the button and then enable the element that you want. Please share your code and I can modify accordingly.

Comment: Pooja .... please use this as well android:clickable="false" along with enabled attribute

Comment: Cannot find android:enabled attribute

Comment: Please share your code or screenshot of the code so that I can look into it.